# Always show last tooltip on all datasets, leave the rest to display on hover? ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

I'm a little stuck on how I would achieve this since it's a little unorthodox in relation to what the plugin does.

I'm attempting for each dataset to keep the last tooltip open at all times and leave the rest to be displayed on hover.

Currently, I'm using this to keep them all displayed:

```
    Chart.plugins.register({
        beforeRender: function (chart) {
            if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
                chart.pluginTooltips = [];
                chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                    console.log(chart);
                    chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (sector, j) {
                        console.log(sector);
                        chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                            _chart: chart.chart,
                            _chartInstance: chart,
                            _data: chart.data,
                            _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                            _active: [sector]
                        }, chart));
                    });
                });

                chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
            }
        },
        afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
            if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
                if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
                    if (easing !== 1) {
                        return;
                    }
                    chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
                }

                chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
                Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
                    tooltip.initialize();
                    tooltip.update();
                    tooltip.pivot();
                    tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
                });
                chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to only do this for the last tooltip in each dataset?

I've come across a way to hide tooltips:

```
filter: function (tooltipItem, data) {
    var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
    if (label === labels[labels.length - 1]) {
        console.log(tooltipItem);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But this just doesn't display them whatsoever since it's returning `false`.

Ultimately it will look like this, with the other tooltips displaying on hover of the corresponding node:

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to use [`chartjs-plugin-datalabels`](https://master--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) for such task.

You can try it out directly on their pages - [scriptable interactions](https://master--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/scriptable/interactions.html)

### setup

Setting some random data:

```
var DATA_COUNT = 8;
var labels = [];

Utils.srand(100);

for (var i = 0; i < DATA_COUNT; ++i) {
  labels.push('' + i);
}

var DATA_COUNT = 8;
var labels = [];

Utils.srand(100);

for (var i = 0; i < DATA_COUNT; ++i) {
  labels.push('' + i);
}
```

### config

Here I did some changes

```
{
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'France',
      backgroundColor: Utils.color(0),
      borderColor: Utils.color(0),
      data: Utils.numbers({
        count: DATA_COUNT,
        min: 10,
        max: 100
      }),
      datalabels: {
        align: function(context) {
          return context.active ? 'start' : 'center';
        }
      }
    }, {
      label: 'Canada',
      backgroundColor: Utils.color(1),
      borderColor: Utils.color(1),
      data: Utils.numbers({
        count: DATA_COUNT,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      })
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      backgroundColor: Utils.color(2),
      borderColor: Utils.color(2),
      data: Utils.numbers({
        count: DATA_COUNT,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      }),
      datalabels: {
        align: function(context) {
          return context.active ? 'end' : 'center';
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        backgroundColor: function(context) {
          return context.active ? context.dataset.backgroundColor : 'white';
        },
        borderColor: function(context) {
          return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
        },
        borderRadius: function(context) {
          return context.active ? 0 : 1;
        },
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: function(context) {
          return context.active ? 'white' : context.dataset.backgroundColor;
        },
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
        formatter: function(value, context) {
          value = Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
          if (context.dataIndex === context.dataset.data.length - 1) {
            return context.dataset.label + '\n' + value + '%';
          } else {
            return context.active
              ? context.dataset.label + '\n' + value + '%'
              : ''
          }
        },
        offset: 8,
        padding: 0,
        textAlign: 'center'
      }
    },

    // Core options
    aspectRatio: 5 / 3,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        bottom: 16,
        right: 40,
        left: 8,
        top: 40
      }
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        fill: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

The main part here is:

```
formatter: function(value, context) {
          value = Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
          if (context.dataIndex === context.dataset.data.length - 1) {
            return context.dataset.label + '\n' + value + '%';
          } else {
            return context.active
              ? context.dataset.label + '\n' + value + '%'
              : ''
          }
        },
```

The `formatter:` where I show the label permanently only for `context.dataIndex === context.dataset.data.length - 1`.

In other cases if it is inactive I show only empty box in other case (hover) I show the information.

### How does it look?

- No hover

[image: No hover with mouse]

- Hover with mouse

[image: Hover with mouse]

Comment: tried implementing it, but now my chart doesnt even show

Comment: @tristan202 What did not work for you, coudl you edit the question with what you tried?  On Monday I'll try to create fiddle for it (I'm not currently at my computer).

Comment: I will post an answer underneath with my entire code as it looks quite different from his. I am by no means js pogrammer, so grasping at straws here. I removed all of the plugin related from my code again as it broke my site.

Comment: @tucan Got it working now. I simply had forgotten a comma...

Comment: @tristan202 I'm happy you got it working.

Answer (score -1):

So this is the entire hmtl file with all relevant code. As I said, I am no programmer. This effort is from loads of trial and error, including several bits of code from stackoverflow questions.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        showtempGraph();
    });

    function showtempGraph()
    {
        {
            $.post("temperaturedata.php",
            function (data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                var temptime = [];
                var temp = [];

                for (var i in data) {
                    temptime.push(data[i].timestamp);
                    temp.push(data[i].temperature);
                }
                
                var tempmin = Math.min(...temp);
                var tempmax = Math.max(...temp);

                var charttempdata = {
                    labels: temptime,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Temperatur',
                            pointRadius: 3,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(26, 137, 245, 0.2)',
                            borderColor: 'rgba(26, 137, 245, 1)',
                            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(12, 68, 122, 1)',
                            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
                            data: temp
                        }
                    ]
                };

                var graphtempTarget = $("#tempgraphCanvas");

                var linetempGraph = new Chart(graphtempTarget, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: charttempdata,
                    options: {
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        tooltips: {
                            enabled: true,
                            custom: function(tooltip) {
                                if (!tooltip) return;
                                tooltip.displayColors = false;
                            },
                            callbacks: {
                                title: function(tooltipItems, tempdata) {
                                return 'Klokken: ' + tooltipItems[0].xLabel;    
                                },
                                label: function(tooltipItem, tempdata) {
                                return 'Temperatur: ' + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel).toFixed(2) + 'Â°C';
                                }
                            }

                        },
                        legend: {
                            display: false,
                        },
                        responsive: true,
                        scales: {
                          xAxes: [{
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                displayFormats: {
                                    hour: 'HH:mm'
                                },
                                tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm',
                            },
                            unit : 'day',
                            gridLines: {
                              color: '#999999',
                              lineWidth: 1
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                fontColor: "#fff",
                                }                               
                          }],
                          yAxes: [
                          { 
                            type: 'linear',
                            position: 'left',
                            gridLines: {
                              color: '#999999',
                              lineWidth: 1
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                fontColor: "#fff",
                                }
                          }, {
                            type: 'linear',
                            position: "right",
                            afterUpdate: function(scaleInstance) {
                              console.dir(scaleInstance);
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                              color: '#999999)',
                              lineWidth: 0.5
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                stepSize: tempmax - tempmin,
                                min: tempmin,
                                max: tempmax,
                                mirror: true,
                                padding: -10,
                                fontColor: "#fff",
                                fontSize: 18,
                                callback: function(value) {
                                    return value + 'Â°C';
                                }
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Â°C',
                                fontColor: "#fff",
                                fontSize: 14
                            }                               
                          }]
                        },
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
    </script>
```