# Chart.js I want to show tooltips only on the last data. What should I do?

Tags: javascript

[image: 1]

I want to keep the tooltip displayed only on the last data on the right like the attached image.

Data can be 5 or more.

I've tried a lot to solve this problem, but I still can't solve it.

The tooltip of the last data should always be kept visible and other tooltips should also be displayed when the mouse is hovered.

Please help by using the chart.js library.

Comment: Adding one answered question if this may give you an idea regarding your similar problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63131506/always-show-last-tooltip-on-all-datasets-leave-the-rest-to-display-on-hover-ch

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also saw this article and tried the same test, but it didn't come out.

Comment: @유대경 the first answer in the above url works just like you said. did you import **chartjs-plugin-datalabels**?

Comment: If it's okay, can you share the source you tested?

Comment: @유대경 added codepen.

Answer (score 0):

i made a runnable one.

as in the answer of the above [question url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63131506/always-show-last-tooltip-on-all-datasets-leave-the-rest-to-display-on-hover-ch)
check the `formatter` in the code.

```js
var DATA_COUNT = 8;
var labels = [];

for (var i = 0; i < DATA_COUNT; ++i) {
  labels.push('' + i);
}

var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'France',
        backgroundColor: "#4dc9f6",
        borderColor:"#4dc9f6",
        data: [27.85378086,18.97029321,49.99421296,35.36998457,36.20871914,60.28819444,12.05285494,62.61381173],
        datalabels: {
          align: function(context) {
            return context.active ? 'start' : 'center';
          }
        }
      }, {
        label: 'Canada',
        backgroundColor: '#acc236',
        borderColor: '#acc236',
        data: [88.6098251,75.44710219,31.3173011,75.97350823,81.02066187,81.02666324,51.30015432,52.33496228]
      }, {
        label: 'USA',
        backgroundColor: "#f53794",
        borderColor: "#f53794",
        data: [40.92121056,47.92309671,22.72333676,44.33427641,99.17566872,25.51911866,24.5991941,38.3912037],
        datalabels: {
          align: function(context) {
            return context.active ? 'end' : 'center';
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    options: {
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          backgroundColor: function(context) {
            return context.active ? context.dataset.backgroundColor : 'white';
          },
          borderColor: function(context) {
            return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
          },
          borderRadius: function(context) {
            return context.active ? 0 : 1;
          },
          borderWidth: 1,
          color: function(context) {
            return context.active ? 'white' : context.dataset.backgroundColor;
          },
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          },
          formatter: function(value, context) {
            value = Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
            if (context.dataIndex === context.dataset.data.length - 1) {
              return context.dataset.label + '\n' + value + '%';
            } else {
              return context.active
                ? context.dataset.label + '\n' + value + '%'
                : ''
            }
          },
          offset: 8,
          padding: 0,
          textAlign: 'center'
        }
      },
  
      // Core options
      aspectRatio: 5 / 3,
      layout: {
        padding: {
          bottom: 16,
          right: 40,
          left: 8,
          top: 40
        }
      },
      hover: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false
      },
      elements: {
        line: {
          fill: false
        }
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }]
      }
    }
  } );
```

```css
#wrapper{
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="chart" width="500" height="450"></canvas>
</div>
```

or codepen
https://codepen.io/fver1004/pen/yLKjggX?editors=1111